# Query the Parameters of a Jenkins Job which is triggered using Rebuild Plugin?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I use the Jenkins CLI to create reports every week for the jobs over the week.

```
def deployOnK8sJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('<JOB>')
def jobBuilds=deployOnK8sJob.getBuilds().byTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()-numberOfHoursBack*60*60*1000, System.currentTimeMillis())

println build.number + "  " + build.actions[0].parameters[0].value + "  " + build.actions[0].parameters[1].value + "  " + build.timestamp.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS") + "  " + build.result + "  " + build.actions[0].parameters[3].value + "  " + build.actions[0].parameters[4].value
```

This works fine for me. But if there was a build failure and anyone triggered the job again using the Rebuild Plugin, `build.actions[0].parameters[x]` are not available.

I have a groovy script that collects these reports.

Comment: what do you mean by not available? what error do you get?

Comment: `ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing groovy command.
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parameters for class: hudson.model.CauseAction`

This is exception I get.

Also when I open the job on UI I see a line stating
Rebuilds build <build number>

How do I know through code that this is a rebuild job? That could help too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when using the Rebuild Plugin, `build.actions[0].parameters[x]` are not available because in this case `build.actions[0]` is not from class `ParametersAction` but from class `CauseAction` as the exception you get says.

So, I would recommend to use `build.getAction(ParametersAction.class)` in stead of `build.actions[0]`.